# Please help me correct the sentences - verb tense

Tags: grammar

Please help me correct the sentences. I'm not sure if the tenses are correct.

> 1. Anna had used similar apps before, and she didn't feel they were social enough because all users were anonymous.
> 2. Adam is in a difficult period in his life. He recently went through a difficult breakup and was fired from his job.

Comment: Why do you think that they might be incorrect? What do you think might be wrong with them?

Comment: I'm not sure if the tenses are correct.

Comment: @Mashka Hi, Welcome to ELL. I wouldn't use past perfect at the beginning. She had used similar apps before using which apps? Consider this: She had been using Facebook 10 months ago, then she gave a chance to Instagram 3 months ago. Please note that I'm not saying it's wrong, but there's a better option.

Comment: @orhantorun, _had used_ is completely natural in the first example. It is looking back at her use of similar apps from the current "story time" in the past - that is what the past perfect is for.

Comment: @Colin Fine  Thank you. what doubts me is when I was preparing for the IELTS Academic this was what my tutor told me, and I saw it in a book, I'll edit this comment with the source if I find it

Comment: @ColinFine Could you check page 30 unit 15 in English Grammar in Use by Raymond Murphy (5th edition). I'm not sure if it is legal to take a screenshot and upload it but this page confirms my previous comment. Plus, I agree with you that it is 'natural' but it might cause a problem or cause the OP to lose marks in an exam. During a daily speech, sure it's natural you are from the UK you know better than me if it's natural or not.

Comment: No, I'm haven't got that book, and in any case I'm not interested in checking it. I've given you my opinion as a linguistically aware native speaker. If the book disagrees, then it is not telling the whole story (as textbooks often do not). As for passing an exam: I have no idea. Pedagogues have spent the last two hundred years teaching a made-up language and pretending it's English, so I can quite believe that examiners do the same nonsense.

Comment: @ColinFine That's an interesting point, your last sentence. Do you recommend an article on that?

Comment: Hello @Mashka, we can't really help you much here.  We need more details.  (1) Please tell us the exact source of these quotes.  Are they from a textbook, a story? Did you write them yourself?  (2) Please tell us **why** you are not sure if the tenses are correct.  Be specific!  At the moment this is really just asking us to check your work, you haven't asked a question.

Comment: @orhantorun: I don't know any articles. But David Crystal's book _The Fight for English_ is a good account of it, and there's quite a bit about it in Oliver Kamm's _Accidence Will Happen_.

Comment: @orhan   Scanning part of a page of a book, and uploading it to a site like this for commentary  or educational purposes would generally be fair use or fair dealing, and thus legal. But we ask (insist) that you first OCR it (or re-type it) so that we have text, not an image of text. Free OCXR is available online.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing grammatically wrong with the tenses used in either sentence. Perhaps they are not the correct tenses given the context in which the sentences arise, but we do not have any such context available.

You say that you feel that something in a specific book indicates a problem, but you have not given us a quotation to allow us to discuss it. If you give us a specific quotation, which is fair use and allowed, in a comment to this answer, it can be addressed. I suspect that you misunderstand what was written.